# Implementing application updates in .Net without ClickOnce

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, libraries

I've got a service that is deployed via MSI that I would like to build updates into. I know that ClickOnce exists, but it's not suitable for my requirements. What other application update frameworks / libraries are available for .Net? The service can be restarted without any disruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the Updates Application Block in the Ent Lib. I am not sure if it's in the lastest version. But I had success setting up updates over http (via a web service) using that block.